# When can an ASEL CFI with Commercial AMEL rating provide and log dual given?

Tags: faa-regulations

Specifically
Does not hold MEI.
Has 0 hours in Cessna 310.  Can he provide and log dual given in that Cessna 310?

and,
What if he is not AMEL only ASEL?

Current regulation?
14 CFR 61.51(e)(3)
https://ecfr.federalregister.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A#p-61.51(e)(3)

Comment: I'm not sure what your second paragraph means: "and, What if he is not AMEL only ASEL?" You already mentioned that the CFI is an ASEL CFI only, is there some other scenario you're asking about?

Comment: To me this question is similar to "Can a non CFII instructor provide instrument training"  which the answer should be yes, except he can't provided the training required for a rating.

Answer (score 1):

As PilotDan has stated, instruction in the Cessna 310 can not be logged by either pilot unless the instructor holds an MEI. If either of the pilots does not hold a AMEL rating, that pilot can not log the C310 time as flight time at all. Not even as a safety pilot per 14 CFR 91.109.

Ad hoc training **can** be given by any AMEL rated pilot. It just can’t be logged as any type of flight time by anyone not possessing the proper category and class rating per 61.51. And, it can not be logged as instruction time without an MEI.

Answer (score 0):

In either situation, the CFI can't log dual given and the other pilot can't log dual received, though they could be a safety pilot in the first situation.
The applicable reg is 61.195(b).

Comment: What if the training is not for a rating.   The non CFI is receiving training and it will not apply toward the rating.  All that training will have to be done by a qualified CFI.  Thanks

Comment: I think https://ecfr.federalregister.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-H#p-61.195(b) is the likely the correct answer.  It specifically states "Aircraft ratings" and I was thinking of it more like the "rating" used like "instrument rating"  which seems to have more grey area.